# flutter geolocator: ^8.0.1 not working properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I was trying to use geolocator in my flutter project but i keep getting the following error code when i restart the app:

This is my flutter code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void geolocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            geolocation();
            //Get the current location
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error message display :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
                                        ^
  symbol:   method isMock()
  location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How do i fix this issue because each time i try to run the app i keep getting same error message displayed on my terminal ?

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: You should follow geolocator package readme

Comment: i have update the post with the build.gradle